# Strange Python datetime import problem

Tags: python, datetime, import

Hi
I'm finding this problem to manifest differently on various setups. 
I've had any one of the following work while the others fail, and this changes sometimes (that is one snippet would fail on one setup while the other fail on another)

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow()


import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

For example, I've just upgraded to python 2.7 from 2.6 and the first snippet which worked fine before now errors

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`

which is fine, but the same snippet worked in 2.6, while the second snippet failed. Now its reversed...

This is quite a weird problem...

Thanks
Harel

Comment: I had a similar problem where I'd extracted some date formatting logic into a separate formatting class.  The `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` call worked fine in the original class but failed with the same `AttributeError` mentioned above in my new formatting class.  I also thought it was something that had changed between Python 2.6 and 2.7 but eventually realised that the problem was I'd put my date formatting class into a module called `xxx.format.datetime`, which would of course cause a problem when using an `import datetime` statement and would cause any later `datetime` references to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers here are correct (your import is wrong), but here's a snippet that will make it more clear what's happening when you do that.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> type(datetime)
<class 'module'>
>>> type(datetime.datetime)
<class 'type'>
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> type(datetime)
<class 'type'>
```

Answer (score 4):

IF you're doing `from datetime import datetime`, you need to use `datetime.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`. I can't possibly see how your first snippet could *ever* work.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
>>> datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 3, 14, 10, 36, 30592)
```

Comment: I agree, I can't see how it ever worked - but it did... This is what's so strange about it. Not only it did work, I took a look at production servers and it IS running there with that code...

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that since this is happening in a Django application, perhaps somewhere there's a 'import datetime' that is called by some other component and prevents this from breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. The first snippet is incorrect in both versions.